# dynamic link update in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I am using docker compose to scale the docker containers. Is there any way to create the links dynamically?

I am using --force-recreate option but I think it create a new container. I want to switch the link (HAProxy) to some other container dynamically.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: You can't switch links dynamically, but the container the link is pointing at should be able to change if you use docker 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need a Docker-aware load balancer that is configured to do so.

#### dockercloud/haproxy

Docker produces and open-sources their own HAProxy image that does support this, and does not require your to `--force-recreate`. It does require v2 of docker-compose.

https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: dockercloud/hello-world
  lb:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy
    links:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

> Once the stack is up, you can scale the web service using `docker-compose scale web=3`. dockercloud/haproxy will **automatically reload its configuration**.